# How can i use " \ " for my string in JSON

Tags: json, database, string, postman, invalid-characters

`{ "imageId" : 1, "carId" : 1, "imagePath" : "C:\Users\swaxz\OneDrive\Desktop\New Folder\Images" }`

i am trying to add a image path to my database with postman in json format but i cant type \ inside the string it says **"invalid escape character in string"** how should i add this path to db?

tried it with 'C:\Users\swaxz\OneDrive\Desktop\New Folder\Images'

Comment: Try escaping (doubling) it? `"C:\\Users\\swaxz\\..."`.